# recursive search in java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, graph, routes

I have the following problem:
I have a hashset of Pairs. Pair is a pair of ints. the pair represents "likes".
let's say my set is :<1,2>,<2,1>,<3,1>,<6,7>,<5,7>,<2,6>
this means 1 likes 2 and 2 likes 1 and 3 likes 1 and so on...

What I'm requested to do is to look at those relations as a graph and given two numbers let's say 2 and 6 I have to find whether there is a route in a graph from 2 to 6 with at most 5 edges connecting between them...

how to write a short recursive method that calculates if the route exists?
I wrote the following code:

```
private boolean findPath(int from, int to, int count){
    System.out.println(from+" "+to+" "+count);
    if(from==to && count<=5)
        return true;
    if(count>5)
        return false;
    Iterator<CookingParty.Pair> iter=likesSet.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Pair curr=iter.next();
        if(curr.likes==from && curr.liked==to){
            return true;
        }
        if(curr.likes==from)
            return findPath(curr.liked, to, count+1);

    }

    return false;
}
```

the problem is that it won't continue going over the rest of the possibilities once one was found to be wrong.
how can I change it to work?

this is the update:

```
private boolean findPath(int from, int to, int count){
System.out.println(from+" "+to+" "+count);
    if(from==to && count<=5)
        return true;
    if(count>5)
        return false;
    Iterator<CookingParty.Pair> iter=likesSet.iterator();
    boolean found=false;
    while(iter.hasNext() && !found){
        Pair curr=iter.next();
        if(curr.likes==from && curr.liked==to){
            found=true;
            return found;
        }
        if(curr.likes==from)
        return findPath(curr.liked, to, count+1);

    }

    return found;
```

}

Comment: what does it mean? it means I need to format my questions better?

Comment: Do you have any code at all our do you want other people to do all the work for you?

Comment: @mary it is customary here on stackoverflow to click Accept on the answer you choose as being correct for your question. It serves as incentive for the other people here trying to help others.

Comment: what is the size of graph? what is your main consideration, memory, speed, completeness? These questions will completely change the structure of an answer..

Comment: I have no idea what size they will give me. they said there will no be requirements for performance as long as it will run in time that is ok the code I gave is basically ok for the requirements side but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you return as soon as you find a pair where `curr.likes == from`. To explore also other paths, you mustn't immediately return in the while loop, but while you haven't yet found a path, check for further possibilities.

```
boolean found = false;
while(iter.hasNext() && !found){
  // check a path
}
return found;
```

Re update: You are still returning in the loop. That's okay in the case where you found a path, but you absolutely must not return in the general case. If `curr.likes == from` and `curr.liked != to`, check that path *and update the boolean*, do not return. Return after the loop has finished.

Comment: Well, what's the loop body now? If it contains a `return` or no `||`, it's probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To search for a path in a graph you can use Depth-First or Breadth-First search. Depth-first is traditionally recursive because it uses a stack. Have a look at the pseudocode here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode